# Difference between >> and >\> operators?

Tags: bash, rhel

RHEL 6

Is there a difference between the `>>` and `>\>` operators?  I read the following blurb in a RHEL training book:

> "You can add standard output to the end of an existing file with a
>   double redirection arrow with a command such as `ls >\> filelist`

I'm more accustomed to the `>>` operator and when I try both, I get different results.

- Using `>>` seems to append output to the file that follows it (as
  expected).
- Using `>\>` seems to append output to a file literally called **>**

Is this a error in the book I'm reading?  Or am I missing the author's point?

Comment: @Sirex short, but an answer.

Comment: yeah, i guess !

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To append text to a file you use `>>`. To overwrite the data currently in that file, you use `>`. In general, in bash and other shells, you escape special characters using `\`.

So, when you use `echo foo >\>` what you are saying is "redirect to a file called `>`", but that is because you are escaping the second `>`. It is equivalent to using `echo foo > \>` which is the same as `echo foo > '>'`.

So, yes, as Sirex said, that is likely a typo in your book.

Answer (score 12):

looks like a typo. .. ... .. ..

Comment: Thanks. Was wondering if I missing some glaringly simple linux concept here. =)